# Fock matrix elements for RHF formalism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-chemistry, molecular-dynamics

Here I refer to a particular book *Molecular Quantum Mechanics* by Peter W. Atkins and Ronald S. Friedman, but similar derivation could be found in many other texts.

So, when obtaining the explicit form of the Fock matrix elements for [RHF formalism](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=restricted+hartree+fock) (p. 295 in 4th edition), authors go from

[image]

to

[image]

just by mentioning that $\psi_u$ is expanded as a linear combination of basis functions $\theta$.

The only way I could go from the first equation to the second one is by expanding the same spatial orbital $\psi_u$ on the left and on the right sides of integrand expression, i.e. before and after $1/r_{12}$, *differently*,
$$
    \psi_u = \sum_l c_{lu} \theta_{l} \quad \text{"on the left side"} \, , \\
    \psi_u = \sum_m c_{mu} \theta_{m} \quad \text{"on the right side"} \, .
$$

Is it true? And if yes, why on earth this should be done this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense to me. $l$ and $m$ are two different summation indices. If you used the same index, say $l$, you would have only the $c^*_{lu}$ $c_{lu}$ terms, without the cross terms when $l\neq m$.

Comment: Ugh! Yes, of course. Just was fooled by too much extra stuff on top of otherwise pretty simple expansion. Thanks!

Comment: I know the feeling... ;-)